# "Recipient of" versus "Winner of"

Tags: phrase-requests, expression-choice

I am trying to write a long list of awards in a sentence, and have an issue with one of the items in the list. The sentence goes:

"ABC is the recipient of Golman Fellowship (2012), Andrew Bell Best Thesis Award (2013), **Quaker Forum Challenge** (2015), and Gryffindor Prize (2016)."

The sentence goes well with the first two and the last awards, but I am not sure of the third ("recipient of challenge" sounds weird). I could have written "ABC is the winner of Quaker Forum Challenge". But it would require a separate sentence that I am trying to avoid.

I can't replace "recipient of" with "winner of" either, as not all the items in the list were obtained in a contest. So, what could be a good way to include "Quaker Forum Challenge" in a single sentence with other awards?

Comment: "ABC is the recipient of Golman Fellowship, Andrew Bell Best Thesis Award, Gryffindor Prize, and the winner of the Quaker Forum Challenge."

Comment: @PeterShor: Thanks. I should have added that the Quaker Forum Challenge is in the middle of the sentence, and that the list should follow a certain chronological order. I have edited the question now.

Comment: "first place in the Quaker Forum Challenge ..."?

Comment: @PeterShor: Thanks, you are making really good suggestions. Not to make this more difficult, but there was not a first place in the challenge. There were 10 winners. Is there a noun I could use after Quaker Forum Challenge that has the same meaning as "win" but is more formal?

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks. But I can't write "recipient of Quaker Forum Challenge winner".

Comment: I googled Quaker Forum Challenge but couldn't find it.  If I can look at it maybe an alternative phrasing will suggest itself.  Without that, I'll mention one idea to get you thinking: "ABC is the recipient of the Golman Fellowship (2012), the Andrew Bell Best Thesis Award (2013), Quaker Forum Challenge (shared first place, 2015), and the Gryffindor Prize (2016)."

Comment: @aparente001 Thanks. Quaker Forum Challenge doesn't exist just like there is no Mr. ABC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose a more direct structure, and ellipsis (in the notion of being the recipient or having been awarded) on the final prize:

> "ABC  received the Golman Fellowship (2012), the Andrew Bell Best
>   Thesis Award (2013), won the Quaker Forum Challenge (2015), and (got)
>   the Gryffindor Prize (2016)."

Because one can "win" a prize, too. I have added some "the", sounding more natural to me, but I am not a native. Or closer to your sentence, grouping qualificatives:

> "ABC  was a recipient or winner of: Golman Fellowship (2012), Andrew
>   Bell Best Thesis Award (2013), Quaker Forum Challenge (2015), 
>   Gryffindor Prize (2016)."

Comment: +1 for the term `recipient or winner of`, though something tells me it should be preceded by _a_ instead of _the_.

Comment: @LaurentDuval: Thanks! This is perfect. I have used "ABC was a recipient/winner of ..."